# Calculating Sumss Of Maths

Tags: classical-mechanics

I need to work out the total thrust on a vertical wall.

The 1st part of the question:

Imagine a pool having dimensions of (x)m x (x)m and it has a depth of (x)m The density is $(x)kg/m^3$

pmax + pmin / 2

pa x area will then equal the total thrust?

Comment: If your original question has been solved, don't delete the body text! This prevents your question from helping people in the future, and likely ensures that your question will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your evaluation is correct but to be more precise we have to distinguish between

- maximum pressure $P_{max} = 1024 \cdot 9.81 \cdot 1.5$

and

- mean pressure $P=\frac12 P_{max}$

Comment: @Diamonds Ops sorry the depth is 1.5, I was considering 3. m. I fix that.

Comment: @Diamonds Your evaluation is correct but the maximum pressure is $2\times 7534.08 \,Pa$.

Comment: @Diamonds Since the pressure is triangular the resultant $F$ is applied at $2/3$ of $H$ that is $1$ m form the top, then the turning moment with respect to the bottom is equal to $M=F\cdot H/3=F\cdot 0.5$.